# Launching a windowed application from a console application?

Tags: c++, windows

I may be approaching this in completely the wrong way as I am pretty new to the C++ language and the overall way this kind of application should be structured, but I hope to confirm the correct method here.

Essentially, I have one cpp file which operates as a console application & a separate cpp file which runs as a windowed application. I want to be able to launch the windowed application when a certain point is reached within the console application. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Some more detail - The console application acts as a 'server' using winsock to communicate with another console application (the client). When the console server application reaches a certain point (a client connects with it) I wish to then launch the other windowed application I have created which will render certain graphics onscreen using Directx. Currently I have both these cpp files as separate projects in a single C++ 2010 Express solution. Currently, there are no links between the two cpp files and they both operate correctly when run separately.

If any more specifics are required, I can provide them but I really want to find out if this approach in general will work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not running a managed C++ application, then [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is the canonical WIN32 system call to use.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to run the exe from another exe?

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("C:\\Folder\\file.exe");
```

Comment: Yeah, but as they are using VS, I thought they might have been using managed C++.

Comment: Using VS does not imply using managed C++, of course not. Don't you think? I personally think that using managed code is intent to be used for simply graphical apps in C#, for example.